# Custom domain name to my SharePoint Online Site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created SharePoint Online site for my company and don't like to keep standard URL which I got from Microsoft.  How do I add a custom domain name?

Answer (score 5):

This is available in the Admin section under Management | Domains.  From this screen you can add you own domain and set properties for your domains.
[image]